# Adding scopes with Gmail API needs verification but Its a console app

Tags: .net-core, gmail-api

I am working on a console app that uses the Gmail API and I need to use some restricted scopes, the problem is when it asks me to verify my project it wants me to provide a website that I don't have because its a console application, any advice?

Comment: your going to have to have a website for users to read your GDPR and privacy information.  Give them the link to that.

Comment: I understand, thanks!